# Get crash dump for .NET CORE application running on Raspberry3 B+ (Debian9, ARM32)

Tags: .net, linux, raspberry-pi, .net-core

I have an **console application**(.NET CORE 2.1.1) that just open 8 tcp connections for read and write, the data rate for each connection is about 200Byte/second, in most time it runs well until like 7 or 8 hours later ,it **randomly crashes**, I have attached the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` with logging but in these cases it never get called, and I have seem some extra info shown **in console** right at application crashes and quit, they are:

> ./myApp: relocation error: /pathToMyApp/libclrjit.so: symbol pthread_,
>   version GLIBC_2.4 not defined in file libpthread.so.0 with link time
>   reference

and

> Bus error

and

> Aborted

for further debug, I've then followed [enable core dump in linux](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/) to enable core dumps, what I've done:

```
$> mkdir -p /tmp/cores
$> chmod a+rwx /tmp/cores
$> echo "/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

for test, I've keyed in command:

```
$> kill -s SIGSEGV $$
```

I can see dumps created at **/tmp/cores/core.bash.1284.raspberrypi.1532411173**

but I've never see my application created that dump though crashes happens everyday, also, I've even tried manually kill myApp to simulate a crash by:`kill myAppProcessId`, but still no luck to see any dump files.

Later, I've add my app to daemon mode, and this time I also can see sth in syslog:

> Jul 17 08:30:51 raspberrypi systemd[1](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/): myApp.service: Main process
>   exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
>
> Jul 17 08:30:51 raspberrypi systemd[1](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/): myApp.service: Unit entered failed state.
>
> Jul 17 08:30:51
>   raspberrypi systemd[1](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/): myApp.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
>
> Jul 17 08:31:01 raspberrypi systemd[1](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2009/03/13/the-core-pattern/): myApp.service: Service
>   hold-off time over, scheduling restart.

But still, never see any dump files generated at path.

Could anyone help?

Comment: I've read your comment at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/87070/79866 but sorry, I'm unfamiliar with Microsoft things so I'm afraid I can help in this much.

Comment: You are using systemd. Have you checked `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` where the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-coredump.html#) says the core dump will be written out to?

Comment: I've tried `kill processId` both in console and daemon mode, both no dumps in path you mentioned.